# Обращение к свойству через переменную

Tags: php, объекты, properties

Имеется следующий объект (поля могут меняться):

```
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'database_driver' => string 'pdo_mysql' (length=9)
  public 'database_host' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  public 'database_port' => int 3306
  public 'database_name' => string 'default' (length=7)
  public 'database_user' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'test' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'hello' => string 'world' (length=5)
```

И код:

```
public function get($parameter)
{
    return $this->config->$parameter;
}
```

Если я передам в функцию просто переменную без "вложенности" (`'database_driver'`), то всё ок, если передам `'test'`, то тоже ок (вернётся вложенный объект), но если я передам `'test->hello'` или `'test.hello'`, то получаю `null`, хотя хотелось бы увидеть `'world'`. Как правильно обратиться к полю `hello`?

P.s. забыл уточнить, что объект указанный выше находится в `$this->config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял, но скорей всего сработает такой метод:

```
public function get($parameter)
{
    $methods = explode('->', $parameter);

    return array_reduce($methods, function ($carry , $item) {
        return $carry->$item;
    }, $this->config);
}
```

соответственно нужно помнить, что ошибки в переданной строке могут привести к исключениям

Comment: к исключениям ошибки не приведут. варнинги мб, но не исключения

Comment: @teran если предыдущая итерация вернет null то null->method вызовет исключение